# Is there a way to make an element clickable but only if it has text in it?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm creating a browser game similar to Text Twist (https://texttwist2.co/) and wanted to see if there's a way to make the divs clickable, but only if they contain text content? I've got the divs holding the letters designated as:

```
<div id="letter-ball-1" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

Thanks so much!

Tyson

Comment: There's either a click event handler or there isn't. In the handler code, you can check for content and if it's empty, then your handler can just do nothing.

Comment: When you provide a onclick event to any HTML tag, it is clickable, it doesn't matter if it only contain text or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `this` object in an event listener will refer to the element that an event listener is attached to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler) (unless the event listener is an arrow function).

```js
<div id="letter-ball-1" onclick="if (this.textContent === '') { location.href='#'; }" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
```